# How to use the chain rule to differentiate

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation

I have two examples of problems that I don't know how to differentiate.

y = $e^{x^2/3x+2}$      and     y = $-10x^{3x^2-4}$

I know to take the ln on both sides. I just don't understand whereto go afterwards. I am needing a good expanation so I can do these types of problems.

Edit: I don't know If i need to do these using logarithmic differentiation. Could someone explain the chain rule process applied to one of these?

Comment: You do not need logarithmic differentiation for the first one.  All you need is the chain rule.

Comment: Can I do both of them without logarithmic differentiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use logarithmic differentiation, you can proceed as follows:
\begin{gather*}
  \ln y = \frac{x^2}{3x+2} \\
  \frac{1}{y}y' = \frac{(3x+2)(2x) - x^2(3)}{(3x+2)^2} \\
  \frac{1}{y}y' = \frac{3x^2 + 4x}{(3x+2)^2} \\
  y' = y\frac{3x^2+4x}{(3x+2)^2} = e^{x^2/(3x+2)}\frac{3x^2+4x}{(3x+2)^2}.
\end{gather*}
However, it is just as easy, if not easier, to simply use the chain rule:
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x^2/(3x+2)}\right) 
     = e^{x^2/(3x+2)}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^2}{3x+2}\right).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Why do you keep the whole e^x part times the derivative of the exponent?

Comment: In the chain rule approach? That is just the definition of the chain rule together with the fact that the derivative of $e^t$ is $e^t$.

Comment: So is this correct :$e^{x^2/3x+2}$ $-3^{x^2}-4x/{3x+2)^2$  *new to formatting on here sorry*

Comment: You should get the same answer that I got using logarithmic differentiation, since there is only one correct answer! I think you have a sign wrong.

Comment: I got $-3x^2-4x$ over $(3x+2)^2$

Comment: Check how I differentiated that quotient when I did the problem using logarithmic differentiation. It's exactly the same computation. As I said, I think you got a sign wrong.

Comment: Ahh I see. i did the quotient rule wrong. I did the top'*bottom - top*bottm'. I didnt think about the order mattering... I am confused still on how you know to bring the whole e^ part out. Does this mean in the other example I take $-10x^{3x^2 - 4}$ * d/dx of $3x^2 - 4$ ??

Comment: For the second one, logarithmic differentiation is really needed. See @abel's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can do logarithmic differentiation.  let us take the second one. you can try the first one yourself.

$$|y| = 10 x^{3x^2 - 4}$$ and take the $\ln$ both side to get $$\ln|y| = \ln 10 + (3x^2 -4)\ln x$$ now differencing gives you $$\frac{dy}{y} = 6x\ln x\, dx + \frac{(3x^2-4)}x \,dx$$ you can turn that into $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(6x^2\ln x+ 3x^2 - 4)}x.$$

Comment: How did you go from 6x in the second to last step to $6x^2$ in the last step

Comment: @Connor, because there is an $x$ in the denominator of the second term.

Comment: Oh you did that so you could put them both over x. How would this change if the equation was actually $-10^{3x^2-4}$ I thought it was -10x^stuff

Comment: would taking the ln of it be $3x^2-4 ln x$ ?

Comment: i don't quite get what the expression is.

Comment: How would everything change if the problem was y=$-10^{3x^2-4}$

Comment: @Connor, that is much easier. $\ln |y| = (3x^2 - 4)\ln 10$. if difference it you get $\frac 1y \frac{dy}{dx} = 6x \ln 10$

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to take any logarithms, just use the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^2}{3x+2}=\frac{3x^2+4x}{(3x+2)^2}$$
Hence:
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{\frac{x^2}{3x+2}}=\frac{3x^2+4x}{(3x+2)^2}e^{\frac{x^2}{3x+2}}$$
If you insist:
$$\ln(y(x))=\frac{x^2}{3x+2}$$
Differentiating both sides gives:
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=\frac{3x^2+4x}{(3x+2)^2}$$
Hence
$$y'(x)=\frac{3x^2+4x}{(3x+2)^2}y(x)=\frac{3x^2+4x}{(3x+2)^2}e^{\frac{x^2}{3x+2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The point is using the chain rule together. I'll do the second one for you, and you try the first one. $y = -10x^{3x^2}-4 \implies y+4 = -10x^{3x^2} \implies \ln(y+4) = 3x^2\ln(-10x).$

Now we notice that $(y+4)' = y'$, and apply $\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}$ on both sides: $$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} \left(\ln(y+4)\right)= \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\left(3x^2\ln(-10x)\right) \implies \frac{1}{y+4} \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = 6x\ln(-10x) + 3x^2 \frac{(-10)}{(-10x)},$$ where we used the chain rule and my previous remark in the LHS, and the usual product rule in the RHS. Proceeding: $$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = (y+4)\left(6x\ln(-10x)+3x\right) \implies \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} =(-10x^{3x^2})\left(6x\ln(-10x)+3x\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is the answer to your first problem.]

Do the second one in a similar fashion.

Comment: This is the complete answer which I got...